# python nested dictionaries loop

Tags: python

Is there a better / cleaner / shorter way of getting the same output as the following?

```
import plistlib
pl = plistlib.readPlist('/Users/username/Documents/wifi1.plist')

n = len(pl)
count = 0
while (count < n):
    print('----------------')
    print(pl[count]['NOISE'])
    print(pl[count]['RSSI'])
    print(pl[count]['SSID_STR'])
    print(pl[count]['BSSID'])
    count += 1
```

I have tried:

```
for sub_dict in pl.values():
    print(sub_dict['NOISE'], sub_dict['RSSI'], sub_dict['SSID_STR'], sub_dict['BSSID'])
```

but I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plistread.py", line 17, in <module>
    for sub_dict in pl.values():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: Have you tried `for sub_dict in pl:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need:

```
for sub_dict in pl:
```

Since `pl` is a list, iterating through that list will give you each sub dictionary in turn.

A simple example:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> for x in l:
...   print x,
... 
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Yes perfect. Why do I refer to it as pl not pl()? Is it because it is not a function?

Comment: Correct.  `pl` is a list, not a function, so it shouldn't be "called".

Comment: I'm just waiting for the time to count down so I can accept you answer... Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you could use a >>>for in<<< statement

```
for sub_dict in pl:
```

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Answer (score 2):

pl is a list, not a dictionary.

So, you should iterate pl by:

```
for sub_dict in pl:
    print(sub_dict['NOISE'], sub_dict['RSSI'], sub_dict['SSID_STR'], sub_dict['BSSID'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
keys = ['NOISE', 'RSSI' ... rest of keys]
input = [{'NOISE':1, 'RSSI':2 ... rest of data}, {'NOISE':11, 'RSSI':22 ... rest of data} ... rest of data]

data = [[sub_dict[key] for key in keys] for sub_dict in input]
```